# eventListener for tracking changes from input TextBox in webWhatsApp

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I am working on a chrome extension. I want to track the changes from the message box. The problem here is, in webWhatsApp, each line after a `\n` is treated as a new `<p>` element. A new `<p>` element is created when `enter (\n)` is encountered from the user side.
Here's an example:

[image]

Here is the HTML from inspect element:

[image]

How do I track the complete message using a eventListener, and where should I add a new eventListner.

I tried something like this (without an eventListner):

```js
const [draftmsg,setDraftMsg]=useState("");
async function getMessages(){
  let inputBoxes=document.querySelectorAll("p.selectable-text");
  // console.log(inputBoxes);
  if(!(inputBoxes.length==1 && (inputBoxes[0] as HTMLElement).innerText=="\n"))
  {
    for(let i=0;i<inputBoxes.length;i++)
    {
      let tempmsg=draftmsg;
      tempmsg+=(inputBoxes[i] as HTMLElement).innerText+'\n';
      await setDraftMsg(tempmsg);
    }
  }
  console.log(draftmsg);
  setTimeout(getMessages,2000);
}
setTimeout(getMessages,1000);
```

But the results were pretty weird:
For the following message:

[image]

My `console.log()` output this:

[image]

Please Help. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: "How do I track the complete message using a eventListener, and where should I add a new eventListner." --- [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) should be what you need.